# FormAlchemy template rendering

Tags: python, flask, formalchemy

I was experimenting with FormAlchemy with django, flask, pyramid frameworks. Used SQLAlchemy==0.7 and FormAlchemy==1.4.2. Followed the documentation available online. However faced some strange problems. Did manage to get workaround, but dont understand why the rendering problem happened.

After passing `form = FieldSet(User).render()` to jinja2 or mako renderer, the total automatically generated html form should be rendered in page, excluding the  tag. However the template variables, `${form}` or `{{ form }}` are not rendered as form. Instead they are plain text!!

Here's the view:

```
def index():
    import formalchemy
    from models import User
    fs = formalchemy.FieldSet(User)
    #fs.rebind(with_prefix=True)
    opts=[('Google','1'),('Yahoo','2'),('MSN','3')]
    fs.configure(options=[
        fs.name.label('Full Name'),
        fs.email.dropdown(opts)
    ])

    form = fs

    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

Here's the template:

> {{ form.render() }}

Here's the output..!!:

[image]

Shouldn't it be a form?!...

This problem is not shown in latest version of FormAlchemy==1.5.5...but there it has another problem. 
The Email field options i used was a test. FormAlchemy==1.5.5 dont support or render the Option Select fields appropriately....That's why i chose version 1.4.2.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try `{{ form.render()|e }}`

Read more http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-manual-escaping